# How to activate Unique Constraint on the RavenDB serverside?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm using version 3.5 and read the documentation here https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/server/bundles/unique-constraints#installation on how to install/activate it on the serverside.

[image]

But i dont understand any single step in this...

"Drop the **Raven.Bundles.UniqueConstraints** assembly in the **Plugins directory**". Where is the assembly and plugins directory?

"simply add **Unique Constraints** to **Raven/ActiveBundles** configuration in the global configuration file". Is it a string or what is it? And where is the global configuration file?

"or setup a new database with the **unique constraints bundle** turned on using API or the Studio". When i create a new database, it doesn't give me any option to turn on the **unique constraints bundle**, but it gives me options such as encryptions, replication etc...

[image]

Hope someone can help me out on this :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the plugins directory?

The [docs on plugins](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/server/plugins/what-are-plugins) shows that it's under ~/Plugins by default. That is, it should be a root folder under the RavenDB server directory. So, wherever you installed Raven server, you should create a Plugins directory under that.

Here's my working example:
[image]

> it doesn't give me any option to turn on the unique constraints bundle

Put Raven.Bundles.UniqueConstraints.dll inside the Plugins folder. Restart your Raven server. Then, load up the Studio, and you'll see the option for Unique Constraints:

[image]